# Open the SSH Door to a Knocking Friend

Tags: debian, ssh, openssh, connection-sharing

I am logged into my Debian machine.  I want my friend to get in via SSH.  He comes to authenticate as the user `friend`.  My machine asks him for a password.  He does not know the password.  I want to be able to let him in by running a command my session (root) that is already authenticated.  I do not want to tell him the password, or change the password.  I just want to open the door for this session.

Is there just a way to tell Linux "OK, this authentication that is trying to come in right now is good.  Let it in."?

Comment: Usual approach is change your password to something else, let him in using your temporary password, and then change your password back to its original

Comment: @steve Yea... but is there a more awesome way where you just snap your fingers and they are in?

Comment: Why can't you use a classical public key authentification.... ?

Comment: SSH keys: https://www.debian.org/devel/passwordlessssh

Comment: Why do you ask?

Comment: SSH cannot connect to an existing terminal, it creates a new one every connection.

Comment: Just add an user and only allow him to login with public key auth. Then you add him to `/etc/sudoers`. Now he can run just the commands you added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could potentially do this using screen (which you may need to install) and SSH keys.

You need to log in as root and then run 'screen -US friend' (install if necessary), run whatever commands you need to do, and the detach from that (using 'Ctrl-A D') to leave it running.

Then in /root/.authorized_keys add your friend's id_rsa.pub or id_dsa.pub key.

With that, your friend can then ssh to root@yourmachine, then run 'screen -UDR friend' to reattach to the screen terminal, see what you've already done in it, and run

Once your friend has finished, remove their key from /root/.authorized_keys right away.

The only problem with this is that you will not be able to see what your friend is doing.

Better would be for you to su to root in a terminal window and then use something like VNC, LogMeIn or TeamViewer to share your desktop to your friend so you can watch what they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I think that something like doesn't exists and maybe never do, is super insecure for example

how do you know that is your friend and not a bad guy using the same user ?

The other problem is that you need to be logged all the time waiting for somebody to knock your door

But I think that I see your problem you don't want a change the password because you can forget change it back or better disable the account

```
Why not use a one time password use solution something like this http://xmodulo.com/secure-ssh-login-one-time-passwords-linux.html
```